# Set Featured Image not opening - Stuck at loading

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, media, library

I am unable to set featured image for posts/pages. The 'set featured image window' opens but never loads and thumbnails.

Then I tried to upload the image using Media, it stucks at crunching. But when I refresh the media page after quire good amount of time, image was uploaded.

Things I have tried:

- Disabling all the plugins
- Regenerating thumbnails

  - gives me this error `function (){if(h){var d=h.length;!function f(b){n.each(b,function(b,c){var d=n.type(c);"function"===d?a.unique&&k.has(c)||h.push(c):c&&c.length&&"string"!==d&&f(c)})}(arguments),b?e=h.length:c&&(g=d,j(c))}return this}`
- Removed all the images from existing Media Libary
- Manually removed UPLOADS/2014 folder.
- Change to default twentyfourteen theme.
- Asked hosting to reset all file permissions

Comment: Is this something new? The website has been working fine up until now? Try clearing your cache and cookies.

Answer (score 1):

If this is still a problem, then you can find my answer on wordpress.org's support forum, it might help: [wordpress.org/support/topic/resize-failure-on-some-images-with-odd-message](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/resize-failure-on-some-images-with-odd-message?replies=10#post-7067924)

> This is a part of a code from the jQuery library, to be specific this
>   part is responsible for handling callbacks. It is displayed, because
>   the reponse from wordpres is unparsable JSON data. If you try to
>   regenerate the thumbnails again in firefox you can open the network
>   tool from the developer tools and read the response from wordpress. In
>   my case it was:
>   `Warning:
>   copy(/var/app/current/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/reindeer.jpg): failed
>   to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /var/app/current/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php on
>   line 231 {"error":""reindeer" (ID 5149) failed to resize. The error
>   message was: The originally uploaded image file cannot be found at
>   <code>http:\/\/mysite.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/11\/reindeer.jpg<\/code>"}`
>
> From there you need to figure out what to do, depending on the error
>   message.

Comment: If you disable php warning, then the Regenerate Thumbnails plugin will display the error messages as the response possibly contains a php warning thus making it impossible for jQuery to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

I would try a couple of things:

1. Check the image itself, I've come across jpg images that have malformed headers so on my linux based desktop (Xubuntu) i can't open them in Thunar/Ristretto but can open them in GIMP.
2. Try re-uploading (after a DB/File backup) the WordPress core files again, perhaps one of them was corrupted during upload/unpacking?